# ASP.NET MVC partial view that updates without controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view that shows a list of `Categories`. I'd like to put that partial view on any page, but I'd like to have it to call to the service and get a list of *categories* by itself without me having to do that in every controller action. Something like webforms in which you can put a code-behind on it.

For eg.

**Actions**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        JobListViewModel model = new JobListViewModel();
        model.Categories= jobService.GetCategories();

        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        Job job = jobService.GetJob(id);
        return View(job);
    }
```

I created a partial that will take the `model.Categories` model and display a list. As you can see, the Index page will work fine, but I do not want to call it again in the Details page. Is there a way to make my partialview call to the `GetCategories()` service by itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Html.RenderAction - that gives the partial view its own controller action.

Comment: So I make an action that returns a partial view and call renderaction?

Comment: Right - aside from using a separate controller action method it is much the same as RenderPartial.

Answer (score 2):

You should also mark you partial action with the attribute [ChildActionOnly].

Answer (score 0):

DVark,

As noted in the accepted answer, for your scenario, RenderAction is the most appropriate.

I thought I'd link a little article that distils my thinking on the topic (i.e. when to use RenderPartial vs RenderAction):

http://cbertolasio.wordpress.com/2010/09/21/mvc-html-renderaction-vs-html-renderpartial/

hope it helps

**[edit]** - as an aside. a year or so ago, i got myself into a few scrapes by not appreciating the power of RenderAction, in favour of RenderPartial. as a result, i had littered the shared view space with lots of partialviews in order to access them from a variety of sources. the moral of the story: know your 'territory' before planting your flag.